# How can I get this MARIE program to work for negatives?

Tags: assembly, marie

I wrote this program that will multiply two numbers together but now I need to make it work for negative numbers, anyone have any advice?

```
org 100
Input a /first factor
Store a /store first factor
Input b /second factor
Store b /store second factor
Load a /load first factor
Skipcond 800 /checks if number is greater than zero
Jump End /skips to the end if zero
load b /load second factor
Skipcond 800 /checks if number is greater than zero
Jump End /skips to the end if zero
Loop, Load b /reloads second factor
Subt One /subtracts one from the second factor
Store b /store the new value of the second factor
Load productAB /load the product of the two number; initially zero
Add a /add first factor to the product
Store productAB /store new value to product
Load b/ load second factor again
Skipcond 400 /end loop if b is equal to 0
Jump Loop /repeats the loop
Load productAB /load the value of productAB; no longer 0
End, output /print out results
Halt /end of program

a, Dec 0
b, Dec 0
productAB, Dec 0 /product of the first two numbers
One, Dec 1
```

Comment: Depending on how this works, it may already do the right thing. Unsigned and signed multiplication that doesn't "widen" the result are the same if you use two's complement negatives. Of course, that makes negative numbers big, so in this naive multiplication that means a *lot* of additions.

Answer (score 3):

Using pseudo code

```
neg = 0
if (a < 0)
    a = -a
    neg = 1
if (b < 0)
    b = -b
    neg ^= 1
productAB = a * b
if (neg)
    productAB = -productAB
```

Comment: You can't program like that in MARIE. There is no way to say b = -b

Comment: @user3003064 I did say it is pseudo code. Can you do `b = 0 - b`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the pseudocode for an optimized version of a multiplication algorithm that works for all integers:

```py
    product = 0
    is_negative = False

    if a < 0 and b > 0 or a > 0 and b < 0:
        is_negative = True

    # make both a and b positive
    if a < 0:
        a = -a
    if b < 0:
        b = -b

    # a should be the bigger number
    if a < b:
        temp = a
        a = b
        b = temp

    # perform multiplication
    for i in range(0, b):
        product += a

    if is_negative:
        return 0-product
    return product
```

By implementing a swapping feature, the code takes less iterations when multiplying a large number and a small number. For example, when multiplying `1000*2`, the revised algorithm simply does `1000+1000` instead of `2+2+...+2`.

Here's the corresponding MARIE.js code:

```
input
store a

input
store b

jns check_sign
jns make_a_pos
jns make_b_pos
jns mult

/ check true sign of product
load negative
Skipcond 400
jump output_negative_product
/ Output  positive product
load product
output
halt
 
check_sign, hex 0
            load a
            Skipcond 000
            jump check_sign_given_a_pos/ do if a >= 0
            
            / if a < 0
            load b 
            Skipcond 000
            jump set_neg_true / a < 0 and b > 0
            JumpI check_sign / a < 0 and b < 0

check_sign_given_a_pos,     load b 
                            Skipcond 000
                            JumpI check_sign / a >= 0 and b >= 0
                            jump set_neg_true / a >= 0 and b < 0

/ negative = 1 and returns to main
set_neg_true,   load one
                store negative
                JumpI check_sign

/ a =  abs(a)
make_a_pos,     hex 0
                load a
                Skipcond 000
                jumpi make_a_pos
                load zero
                subt a
                store a
                jumpi make_a_pos
                
/ b = abs(b)
make_b_pos,     hex 0
                load b
                skipcond 000
                jumpi make_b_pos
                load zero
                subt b
                store b
                jumpi make_b_pos
 
output_negative_product,    load zero
                            Subt  product
                            store product
                            output
                            halt
                    

/ performs product = abs(a) * abs(b), where abs(a) >= abs(b)            
mult,   hex 0
        load a
        subt b
        
        / a < b ?
        skipcond 000
        Jump mult_loop
        
        / swap a and b
        load a
        store temp
        
        load b
        store a
        
        load temp
        store b
        
mult_loop,  load i
            subt b
            / i < b ?
            skipcond 000
            JumpI mult

            load product
            add a / product += a
            store product

            / i++
            load i
            add one
            store i

            jump mult_loop

negative, dec 0 / initially false. 
one, dec 1 
zero, dec 0
i, dec 0
temp, dec 0
a, dec 0
b, dec 0
product, dec 0
```